# как передать действие на страницу через консоль?

Tags: javascript, html, консоль, google-chrome

как передать действие на страницу через консоль? т.е. как ввести через консоль в input текст, и вызвать его обработку (нажать на button)?
например вот такой код

```
<div id="det">
            <span> <input type="text" id="txt" value="" onfocus="this.select();" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) func.names.det.view();"></span>
            <span><input type="button" id="detview" value="View Details" onclick="func.names.det.view();"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ровно так же, как это выглядело бы в коде.

Answer (score 0):

вообщем если у кого то будет подобная задача, можно решить через нечто подобное

```
var txt = [
"roman",
"fedor",
"petr",
"victor"]; 
let i = 0;

while (i < txt.length) {

    document.querySelector("#text").value = txt[i];

    if (document.querySelector("#txt").value != ""){
        document.querySelector("#detview").click();
    } else{
        console.log("fields are not filled correctly");
    }

    i++;
}
```

это вводиться прямо в консоль браузера и страница запускается из консоли